# DocumentFormat.openxml Excel File Reading Issue

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have used DocumentFormat.OpenXml dll in one of my project for reading and writing excel file.

During Reading of Excel File, Let's say for some column say Column1  I am having cell values as "TRUE"  and "FALSE".  When I read this Excel File using Following Code

```
private SharedStringTable sharedStringTable;
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
{

  WorkbookPart workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
  WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.FirstOrDefault();
  SharedStringTablePart sharedStringTablePart = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
  if (sharedStringTablePart != null)
  {
    sharedStringTable = sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
  }
    var sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.Sheets;

    foreach (Sheet sheet in sheets)
    {   
            Worksheet requiredItem = (doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id.Value) as WorksheetPart).Worksheet;
            var sheetData = requiredItem.Elements<SheetData>().First();

            foreach (var rowItem in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
            {
                foreach (var item in rowItem.Elements<Cell>())
                {
                    string requiredText = string.empty;
                    if (item.CellValue != null)
                    {
                        requiredText = item.CellValue.InnerText;
                    }
                }
            }
    }

}
```

At that time for  Cell Values "TRUE" and "FALSE"  i am getting values 1 and 0 Respectively.

Can anyone provide me any way so that I can get values "TRUE" and "FALSE" instead of 1 and 0 ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534.aspx

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams